# Are UDF used by a stored procedure optimised/merged in the SP itself?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, query

The issue has sent me crazy for a few days, I may have found my answer, but I need a confirmation and to check for an eventual easy solution.

When a stored procedure uses some user defined functions, are the UDF plans merged in the main plan and everything get optimised or are they called directly every time?

And suppose it doesn't happen, is there a way to force SQL Server to do it for a specific SP?

Comment: Can you specify what kind of function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it should depend on the type of function. Inline Table-Valued Functions have their definitions substituted into referencing queries, just like what happens with views. This is what is meant by "inline", and why they are not true modules that can be signed, among other differences with the other function types.

Multi-statement Table-Valued Functions and Scalar User-Defined Functions are completely independent modules that are executed separately and have their own plans.

This behavior should have nothing to do with them being referenced in a stored procedure or in an ad hoc query.

Now, whether or not UDFs are called every time, that depends on the type of UDF:

- T-SQL UDFs are executed per row and prevent parallel plans
- SQLCLR UDFs, if they are marked as `IsDeterministic=true;` (is `false` by default), *and* are not doing any data access, do *not* prevent parallel plans and *should* be able to have their return values cached (per query execution, I assume).

All of this is why, whenever possible, it is best to convert T-SQL UDFs into T-SQL Inline TVFs.

Comment: Seems I asked the wrong question, but this is still a valuable piece of knowledge I needed to learn, so +1 and accepted answer. Thank you :-)

Comment: Thanks. But what was the actual thing you were wanting to know about?

Comment: I'll post the question in a moment. Seems I've got at hand a bad case of parameter sniffing without parameter sniffing. Or either I have to admit I have no idea how parameter sniffing happens.

Comment: if you are wanting to know if UDFs can have parameter sniffing issues, I believe the answer is implied in my answer here: Inline TVFs = no, Multi-statement TVFs and Scalar UDFs = yes.

Comment: It's more complicated than that. I have a stored procedure that run slow in a case and very fast in another, and after a few days of messing around I was (wrongly) convinced that it was because of the calls to functions. This DB has been designed to not being queried easily: so the SP calls a view which calls some functions which are calling some functions which are calling some functions, and all of them working on the same 4 tables.

Comment: You should see the query plan...I have a table with a few hundred records, and according to the plan the spool extracts from it 51,000,000 records. And no, not because a join :-D But you just gave me an idea to verify. Thx again!

Comment: That's sounds pretty crazy. Sorry you are having to deal with such a mess. And yeah, I know _exactly_ what you mean by "This DB has been designed to not being queried easily" (unfortunately) ;-)